# case statement to select multiple rows at once

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

I am looking to pull the same columns from two different tables, based on a conditional argument.

So i have stumbled upon the CASE statement which I have not used much before. I have found this will work for me in this mannor, but I would like it if I could do one CASE statement and then select the columns i need, rather then doing it per column.

Here is an example of what I have and working, just seems a little redundant.

```
SELECT TOP(10)
    u1.userid as userid,
    version = CASE
        WHEN (u2.userid IS NULL OR u1.enabled = 0)
        THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END,
    nameOrg = CASE
        WHEN (u2.userid IS NULL OR u1.enabled = 0)
        THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, u1.title)
        ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, u2.title)
    END,
    nameContact = CASE
        WHEN (u2.userid IS NULL OR u1.enabled = 0)
        THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, u1.contact)
        ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, u2.contact)
    END,
    pltName = CASE
        WHEN (u2.userid IS NULL OR u1.enabled = 0)
        THEN p1.name
        ELSE p2.name
    END
FROM
    usr1 u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    usr2 u2
    ON u1.userid = u2.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    plt2 p2
    ON u2.pltid = p2.pltid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    plt1 p1
    ON u1.pltid = p1.pltid
```

Any advise?

- Edit mov 7, 5:22: added join to plt table and pltName case, to add to required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that there is no matching userid in the usr2 dataset, all the fields will be null.  You could use the isnull function to make it a little less verbose as I have done below, but you won't get down to a single line.

```
SELECT TOP(10)
    u1.userid as userid
    ,version = CASE
        WHEN (u2.userid IS NULL OR u1.enabled = 0)
        THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END 
    ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,isnull(u2.title,u1.title)) nameOrg
    ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,isnull(u2.contact,u1.contact)) nameContact
FROM
    usr1 u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    usr2 u2
ON u1.userid = u2.userid
```

Comment: that is a helpful idea, though it does also ignore that fact that there is a secondary condition to the null expression.  That aside I have also added more joins, where in the condition stays the same (checking the first two tables), but the used variables are on different tables just to be sure I get a 100% valid answer.